# How to get workflow history in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to create a web part in which I want to display history of all workflows that failed in the past certain time. The info that I want to get is the workflow name, its location (site URL), initiator and error date time. I am very new to SharePoint with ASP.Net background so I am having a hard time figuring out if there is some way in the API to that?

Kindly share if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Its a hidden list so you can't get to it from All Site Content. You have to type the URL in directly, like below. And once you have the URL of the list you can query the individual fields

```
http://[servername]/[sitename]/lists/Workflow%20History
```

Comment: I am not just interested in the list workflows only but site workflows also. Basically I want to show a summary of all the workflows that have errors / failed.